# Error on emulator using OneTap Google login with Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-emulator, google-one-tap

I have a problem using the OneTap Google login feature on my emulator.

Emulator: Pixel 5 API 31

Android Studio: Giraffe 2022.3.1

**On my physical device it works perfectly** but when I try to login on my emulator the logcat reports:

```
Missing Feature{name=auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, version=8}
```

I tried everything I found in others answers but nothing worked. What I tried so far:

- Clear cache and data from Google app.
- Reboot the emulator.
- Setup process.
- Different emulator with different API version.
- Checked `google-services.json` and `SHA1`.

Has someone encountered this problem too recently ? How can I solve ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help with the code and error. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: But I'm not using Compose and my problem is only with the emulator, in my physical device it works fine.